# Posting and getting an object that contains a list of object

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jdbctemplate

I have two entity classes, recipe and ingredient. each recipe contains a list of ingredients and each ingredient holds a recipe id as a foreign key. the entity classes look something like this

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "recipe", schema = "public")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Recipe {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY
    )
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "instructions")
    private String instructions;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "recipe")
    private List<Ingredient> ingredients;
    @JsonProperty("date_added")
    private String dateAdded;
    @JsonProperty("last_edited")
    private String lastEdited;

    public Recipe(long id, String name, String instructions, String dateAdded, String lastEdited) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.instructions = instructions;
        this.dateAdded = dateAdded;
        this.lastEdited = lastEdited;
    }
}
```

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Ingredient")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Ingredient {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY
    )
    @JsonProperty("ingredient_id")
    private long ingredient_ID;
    @JsonProperty("ingredient_name")
    private String ingredientName;
    @Column(name = "amount")
    private int amount;
    @Column(name = "unit")
    private String unit;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "recipe_id")
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonIgnore
    private Recipe recipe;

    public Ingredient(long ingredient_ID, String ingredientName, int amount, String unit) {
        this.ingredient_ID = ingredient_ID;
        this.ingredientName = ingredientName;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.unit = unit;
    }
}
```

The problem arises when I try to post a recipe. Originally I thought I would create the recipe (without the id)->let the database generate the id->create the ingredients in a loop whilst passing the id generated to each ingredient. However, despite successfully generating the id in the database, I couldn't figure out how to "get" the id. Instead, I ended up searching for the id by comparing the other attributes like this

```
                SELECT id FROM public.recipe
                WHERE name = ? AND instructions = ? AND date_added = ? AND last_edited = ?
```

Obviously not a great solution since I cannot guarantee the uniqueness of the 4 attributes and any un-unique combinations will result in an error (from queryforobject).

the whole service looks sth like this

```
    //retrieve the id of the recipe using the name instructions and date_added fields
    //called exclusively by postRecipes
    public long getIDByNID(Recipe recipe){
        String name = recipe.getName();
        String instruction = recipe.getInstructions();
        String dateAdded = recipe.getDateAdded();
        String lastEdited = recipe.getLastEdited();
        var sql = """
                SELECT id FROM public.recipe
                WHERE name = ? AND instructions = ? AND date_added = ? AND last_edited = ?
                """;

        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, Long.class, name, instruction,dateAdded,lastEdited);
    }


    //insert a recipe with only name instruction and date_added
    //to generate a new recipe object with an id
    //called exclusively by postRecipes
    public void postRecipe(Recipe recipe){
        var sql = """
                INSERT INTO public.recipe ("name", "instructions","date_added","last_edited")
                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
                """;
        jdbcTemplate.update(
                sql,
                recipe.getName(),
                recipe.getInstructions(),
                recipe.getDateAdded(),
                recipe.getLastEdited()
        );
    }

    public void postRecipes(Recipe recipe) {
        postRecipe(recipe);
        var ingredientSQL = """
                INSERT INTO public.ingredient("ingredient_name", "amount", "unit","recipe_id")
                VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)
                """;
        int i = 0;
        recipe.setId(getIDByNID(recipe));
        while(i<recipe.getIngredients().size()){
            Ingredient ingredient = recipe.getIngredients().get(i);
            jdbcTemplate.update(
                    ingredientSQL,
                    ingredient.getIngredientName(),
                    ingredient.getAmount(),
                    ingredient.getUnit(),
                    recipe.getId()
            );
            i++;
        }
    }
```

The getter is also quite messy. Although I can't think of anything obviously wrong with it, but surely there is an easier way to get sth.

```
    public List<Recipe> getRecipes(){
        //id, name, ingredient_name, amount, unit, instructions, date_added, last_edited
        var sql = """
            SELECT id, name, ingredient_id, ingredient_name, amount, unit, instructions, date_added, last_edited
            FROM public.recipe
            INNER JOIN public.ingredient ON id = recipe_id
            LIMIT 50
            """;
        return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new RecipeSetExtractor());
    }
```

```
    public List<Recipe> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
        List<Ingredient> ingredientList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Recipe> recipeList = new ArrayList<>();
        Recipe recipe = new Recipe();
        long id = -1;
        int i = 0;
        while(rs.next()) {
            if(id==-1){
                id = rs.getLong("id");
                recipe = new Recipe(
                        rs.getLong("id"),
                        rs.getString("name"),
                        rs.getString("instructions"),
                        rs.getString("date_added"),
                        rs.getString("last_edited"));
            }
            if(rs.getLong("id")!=id){
                id = rs.getLong("id");
                recipe.setIngredients(ingredientList);
                recipeList.add(recipe);
                ingredientList = new ArrayList<>();
                recipe = new Recipe(
                        rs.getLong("id"),
                        rs.getString("name"),
                        rs.getString("instructions"),
                        rs.getString("date_added"),
                        rs.getString("last_edited"));
            }
            ingredientList.add(new Ingredient(
                    rs.getLong("ingredient_id"),
                    rs.getString("ingredient_name"),
                    rs.getInt("amount"),
                    rs.getString("unit")));
            i++;
        }
        recipe.setIngredients(ingredientList);
        recipeList.add(recipe);
        return recipeList;
    }
```

Comment: Do not use the Entity classes as API object. That is very bad architecture

Comment: does that mean I should have a different class for Entity and Data

Comment: Yes that is what i mean

Answer (score 0):

According to me, you have to restructure your code properly, and as Jens said you should avoid using entities and start using DTOs (Data Transfer Objects).
Considering you won't get an ID when saving recipes. You can store timestamps in the DB so that it can act as a unique field for any recipe plus you can convert it to a given time based on the location of the client rather than storing the actual dates in the database. If you are able to do that change then you can see how I have written the APIs. If not you can see how I have used DTOs and how the code is structured.

Create 3 packages namely Models, Controllers and Services

In Models,

Recipe class :

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Recipe {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "instructions")
    private String instructions;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "recipe")
    private List<Ingredient> ingredients;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "bigint default 0")
    private BigInteger dateAdded;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "bigint default 0")
    private BigInteger lastEdited;


}
```

Ingredient class:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Ingredient {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    private String ingredientName;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "int default 0")
    private int amount;

    private String unit;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "recipe_id")
    private Recipe recipe;

}
```

In Controllers,

RecipeConroller class:

```
@RestController
public class RecipeController {

    @Autowired
    private RecipeService recipeService;

    @PostMapping("/addRecipe")
    public void addRecipe(@RequestBody RecipeDTO recipeDTO) {
        recipeService.addRecipe(recipeDTO);
    }


    @GetMapping("/getRecipes")
    public List<RecipeDTO> getAllRecipes() {
        return recipeService.getAllRecipes();
    }


}
```

In Services ,

RecipeService class :

```
@Service
public class RecipeService {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private IngredientService ingredientService;


    public void addRecipe(RecipeDTO recipeDTO) {
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        BigInteger dateAdded = BigInteger.valueOf(currentTime);
        System.out.println("CURRENT TIME :" + currentTime);

        jdbcTemplate.update(
                "INSERT INTO recipe(name,instructions,date_added,last_edited) VALUE(?,?,?,?)",
                recipeDTO.getName() ,recipeDTO.getInstructions() ,dateAdded ,dateAdded
        );

        var result = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT id FROM recipe WHERE last_edited = ?" ,Long.class ,currentTime);


        ingredientService.addIngredients(recipeDTO.getIngredients() ,result);
    }

    public List<RecipeDTO> getAllRecipes() {
        String sqlQuery = "SELECT id,name,instructions,date_added,last_edited FROM recipe";

        List<RecipeDTO> recipeDTOS =  jdbcTemplate.query(
                sqlQuery,
                (rs, rowNum) ->
                       new RecipeDTO(
                               rs.getLong("id"),
                               rs.getString("name"),
                               rs.getString("instructions"),
                               rs.getObject("date_added" ,BigInteger.class),
                               rs.getObject("last_edited" ,BigInteger.class)
                       )
        );

       for(RecipeDTO recipeDTO : recipeDTOS){
           List<IngredientDTO> ingredientDTOS = ingredientService.getIngredientsByRecipeId(recipeDTO.getId());
           recipeDTO.setIngredients(ingredientDTOS);
       }
       return recipeDTOS;
    }

}
```

IngredientService class :

```
@Service
public class IngredientService {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void addIngredients(List<IngredientDTO> ingredientDTOS, Long recipeId) {
        if (ingredientDTOS != null) {
            for (IngredientDTO ingredientDTO : ingredientDTOS) {

                jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO ingredient(ingredient_name,amount,unit,recipe_id) VALUE(?,?,?,?)",
                        ingredientDTO.getIngredientName(), ingredientDTO.getAmount(), ingredientDTO.getUnit(), recipeId
                );
            }
        }
    }

    public List<IngredientDTO> getIngredientsByRecipeId(long recipeId) {
        String sqlQuery = "SELECT id ,ingredient_name,amount,unit,recipe_id FROM ingredient WHERE recipe_id = ?";

        return jdbcTemplate.query(
                sqlQuery,
                (rs, rowNum) ->
                        new IngredientDTO(
                                rs.getLong("id"),
                                rs.getString("ingredient_name"),
                                rs.getInt("amount"),
                                rs.getString("unit"),
                                rs.getLong("recipe_id")
                        ),
                recipeId
        );
    }


}
```

RecipeDTO :

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RecipeDTO {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String instructions;
    private List<IngredientDTO> ingredients;
    private BigInteger dateAdded;
    private BigInteger lastEdited;


    public RecipeDTO(long id, String name, String instructions, BigInteger dateAdded, BigInteger lastEdited) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.instructions = instructions;
        this.dateAdded = dateAdded;
        this.lastEdited = lastEdited;
    }
}
```

IngredientDTO :

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class IngredientDTO {

    private long id;
    private String ingredientName;
    private int amount;
    private String unit;
    private long recipeId;



}
```

[Controllers and DTOs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ2nt.png)
[Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0dKc.png)

I have made your requirements as 2 separate APIs.If you have difficulties understanding let me know.

Comment: hi sorry for the late reply. I have been having some troubles with my program since adding the DTOS. the ingredientDTOs seems to be null for some reason even though all I did was replacing the ingredient/recipe in the orginal code with ingredientDTO/recipeDTO. Also could you maybe post the DTO classes as well? thanx

Comment: Yeah, sure I will include it in the above answer.